# Web.config problems with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

New to asp.net when I go into the `web.config` I can't find the `<entityframework>` section in it to change some settings. I'm currently using this guide http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started to help me with my project. No idea what I've done wrong as I've followed each step.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <!--   For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880   --> <configuration>   <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->   <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 --></configSections>   <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LoftBook" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-LoftBook-20151211033930.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-LoftBook-20151211033930;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   </connectionStrings>   <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />   </appSettings>   <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      </system.Web>   -->   <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />   </system.web>   <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </modules>   </system.webServer>   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>   </runtime> </configuration>
```

```
using System; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Web; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using LoftBook.Models;

namespace LoftBook.DAL {
    public class LBInitializer : System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<LBContext>
    {

        protected override void Seed(LBContext context)
        {
            var sires = new List<Sire>
            {
                new Sire {RingNo ="IHU S 2009 1143", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
                new Sire {RingNo ="IHU S 2011 1467", Colour = "Red", Breed = "Jan Arden",},
                new Sire {RingNo ="IHU S 2012 2367", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
            
            };

            sires.ForEach(s => context.Sires.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var dams = new List<Dam>
            {
                new Dam {RingNo ="IHU S 2009 5362", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
                new Dam {RingNo ="IHU S 2011 9203", Colour = "Red", Breed = "Jan Arden",},
                new Dam {RingNo ="IHU S 2012 2315", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
            
            };

            dams.ForEach(s => context.Dams.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();


            var youngsters = new List<Youngster>
            {
                new Youngster {RingNo ="IHU S 2015 001", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
                new Youngster {RingNo ="IHU S 2015 002", Colour = "Red", Breed = "Jan Arden",},
                new Youngster {RingNo ="IHU S 2015 003", Colour = "Blue", Breed = "Jassen",},
            
            };

            youngsters.ForEach(s => context.Youngsters.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var pairs = new List<Pair>
            {
                new Pair {Sire = "IHU S 2009 1143", Dam = "IHU S 2009 5362", Paired = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-01"), Hatched = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-20"), Youngster = "IHU S 2015 001",},
                new Pair {Sire = "IHU S 2011 1467", Dam = "IHU S 2011 9203", Paired = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-01"), Hatched = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-19"), Youngster = "IHU S 2015 002",},
                new Pair {Sire = "IHU S 2012 2367", Dam = "IHU S 2012 2315", Paired = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-01"), Hatched = DateTime.Parse("2015-12-22"), Youngster = "IHU S 2015 003",},
            };

            pairs.ForEach(s => context.Pairs.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    } }
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; 
using System.Linq; using System.Web; 
using System.Data.Entity; 
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions; 
using LoftBook.Models;

namespace LoftBook.DAL {
    public class LBContext : DbContext
    {

        public LBContext()
            : base("LBContext")
        {

        }


        public DbSet<Dam> Dams { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sire> Sires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Pair> Pairs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Youngster> Youngsters { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }
    } }
```

Thanks in advance

Jason

Comment: what settings do you want to change?  What are the observed results vs. your expected results?  How about a snipped of the part of the web.config you're having an issue with?

Comment: If there are multiple projects within your solution, make sure you are looking at the correct configuration file. If you are working in an MVC project, make sure you are looking at the web.config on the root and not one in an MVC area or other folder.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I'm trying to "Set up EF to use a SQL Server Express LocalDB database" that's the heading from the guide I'm following off the asp.net site. I've made sure I checked the root folder and not the other but it's just not there very confusing!

Comment: Are your Data Models and DbContext in the Same Project as your mvc web project or do you have a DataAccessLayer or a BusinessLocicLayer?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all** , I think you didn't add Entity framework to your project .

**1**.Install Entity First from Nuget Package Manager

**2**.Right click on Models in your project , then  **Add>New Item** to add a database to your project

Here is the full guide for   [Get Start with Entity Framework](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/creating-the-web-application)

this article explain that you have designed a databse in **sql server** with **diagrams** and you want **generate models** from it (the easiest way that i tried before)

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have it installed I checked Nuget Package Manager and it's installed in my project. It still doesn't show up in the web.config. I'm trying to do this "Set up EF to use a SQL Server Express LocalDB database" that's the heading fro  the guide I'm following.

Comment: please  check your links , your links doesn't work . and with which version of visual studio you working?

Comment: ok . first check 'Reference' in solution browser to find out you have 'EntityFramework' , 'EntityFramework.SqlServer' and etc has keyword 'entity' . if you didn't find them , right click on Reference and add by click on 'Add Reference' and search for 'Entity' keyword and add them . then click right on your project and click on 'Propertise' . In 'Package/Publish SQL' tab you can add connection string for your EF .

Comment: I've both EntityFramework and EntityFramework.SqlServer in my reference

Comment: Did you check the 'Package/Publish SQL' tab?

Comment: I opened the 'Package/Publish SQL' tab and there was nothing there so I enabled it and added my web.config to it?

Comment: i suggest you make another project and try to add EF to it . if everything was right , add your another part of roject to newer project .

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and see how I get on. Been one problem after another. Could it do with that fact I'm using my Mac to log into the college computer using citrix to use visual studios?

Comment: maybe jason . I suggest try with windows !